# How to open a clean terminal in Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: terminal, osx-lion

Whenever I open a terminal, the last used commands appear.

I'd like to get a clean terminal when I open it, but I haven't found how to do it.

For example if while using the terminal I do:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder...etc
```

and then I close the terminal. Next time I open the terminal I will see this same line grayed out (to indicate it's a command I used last time I opened the terminal) and a line to start writing underneath.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you see when you open the terminal?

Comment: I aliased `clear` to a proper output window clearing command on my machine. Will look it up in about six hours unless someone else provides an answer before then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following at the very end of `.bash_profile`:

```
printf '\033c'
```

This will *really* clear the Terminal. I even defined the following function, since I didn't like the scrolling behavior of the default `clear`:

```
function clear {
    printf '\033c'
}
```

I think it's the same as a *hard reset* of the Terminal (`Cmd-Opt-R`), but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: this is not the answer though - Lion restores windows from the previous Terminal session. What you need to do is turn off Resume for Terminal like Josh says below. Also, you need to learn to close windows you're no longer using before quitting the application in Lion.

Comment: @w00t Well I guess you're understanding the question differently than me. The user is only concerned about the grey lines related to his previous session; nowhere are the windows actually mentioned. Sessions are also new; which is easily visible when `cd`ing somewhere, then closing and reopening Terminal. There's just the grey lines from the end of the previous session. Between my answer and the others', he surely can find a solution to his problem, whichever interpretation is correct. By the way, my answer has the checkmark, although it wasn't the first one, so it can't be *that* bad.

Comment: `ESC c` is "Full Reset (RIS)", which is the same as Shell > Send Hard Reset; however, that merely clears the display and resets the terminal state. It doesn't clear the scrollback. If all Proxify is looking for is a way to clear the screen, just use the normal `clear` command (not the `clear` function given in this answer). Otherwise, `ESC c` is insufficient, and performs a completely unnecessary terminal reset.

Comment: @ChrisPage I could have sworn that it cleared the scrollback too. Do you have still have a 10.6 system around? When I posted this, I was still on Snow Leopard. On Lion it doesn't make a difference, just like you wrote.

Comment: @DanielBeck Prior to 10.7, the Erase in Display (ED) escape sequence (ESC [ … J) could only clear the screen, not the scrollback. Starting in 10.7, Terminal supports the xterm ED variant that clears the scrollback: ESC [ 3 J http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

Comment: @ChrisPage hooray for you! To clear both buffers (screen and scroll), I ended up with: echo -en '\033[3J\033c' (printf is a bash builtin, might no be in other shells).

Comment: @JerrySeeger `/bin/echo` doesn't support `-e`, so you're dependent on shell builtins as well.

Answer (score 10):

From my own experience, when I [disabled Lion's Resume feature](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/07/20/how-to-disable-lions-resume-feature/), this stopped Terminal storing session history.

Comment: It looks like this solves this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Lion's window resume feature is set on an application by application basis. You can stop this in Terminal with the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

Because you're editing the Terminal settings while having Terminal open, you'll need to close and restart Terminal twice before seeing the effect.

Comment: This should be the answer in my opinion. This sets the defaults for all of Mac OS X.

Answer (score 7):

Command-K clears the Scrollback.

Comment: This is the simplest and best solution for just a permanent clear to a few windows, but not a permanent disable of the feature.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is not play with workarounds, but you want to know where is stored on disk the "grey text" you see in Terminal and remove it.

This text is stored here : ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState.

Remove folder and you will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

One solution: export `TERM` with a reasonable value like "xterm", and place the `clear` command on the last line of your `~/.bash_profile`. Other solutions could be devised.

Comment: `clear` doesn't clear the Terminal, it only scrolls down a page.

Comment: @DanielBeck `clear` clears the terminal display. In some cases it does so by moving the screen contents into the scrollback (but not always, e.g., when the alternate screen is selected).

Comment: It's unnecessary to modify the value of TERM unless one has already modified it from the default. By default, Terminal sets TERM to xterm-color (versions prior to 10.7) or xterm-256color (Lion 10.7 and later), both of which support `clear`.

Comment: @ChrisPage How often is that the case when launching Terminal?

Comment: @DanielBeck I don't understand your question. Unless the user has customized the "Declare terminal as" preference setting to change the value that Terminal sets TERM to, it will be the default, xterm-256color (or xterm-color prior to 10.7). Terminal always sets TERM to the "Declare terminal as" value when creating a terminal session.

Comment: @ChrisPage Sorry, was referring to the alternate screen bit.

Comment: @DanielBeck By default the Erase in Display (ED) escape sequence (ESC [ … J) clears the main screen by scrolling it up to the scrollback. If the alternate screen is selected, it does not save the screen contents anywhere. In addition, if a scroll region is in force and the region has a top margin, the contents are not scrolled into the scrollback. Starting in 10.7, Terminal supports the xterm ED variant that clears the scrollback: ESC [ 3 J http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html