# OS X 10.7: how to prevent Terminal to remember old commands/output

Tags: osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open a clean terminal in Mac OS X Lion?](https://superuser.com/questions/315174/how-to-open-a-clean-terminal-in-mac-os-x-lion)

When opening a new terminal in OS X 10.7, it shows the darkened output of the previous terminal session. How to prevent it?

Comment: exactly the same issue as in: [How to open a clean terminal in Mac OS X Lion?](http://superuser.com/questions/315174/how-to-open-a-clean-terminal-in-mac-os-x-lion)